# ÅÄÖ Characters not being sent correctly in ASP Classic application running on IE10

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, vb6, internet-explorer-10

**Context information**

I have a classic asp site running, built with VBScript

When i input a string into a textfield, the client sends this string to a VB6-DLL.

The dll is responsible to find out if the string already exists in a database-table.

ASP code looks like this:

```
<%if dll.Checkstring(sString) = false then %>
    '-- Code when it fails.
<% else %>
    '-- Code when successful.
<% end if %>
```

And in dll.checkstring:

```
Function checkString(ByVal sString As String) As Boolean

    if existsInFooTable(sString) then
       checkString = true
    else
       checkString = false
    end if 

end function
```

**Problem**

String input in IE8: `"ÄÖÄWFÖWÖLFÖF"`

String input in VB-DLL for verification: `"ÄÖÄWFÖWÖLFÖF"` Matches the
 actual input from IE8.

String input in IE10: `"ÄÖÄWFÖWÖLFÖF"`

String input in VB-DLL for verification: `"Ã„Ã–Ã„WFÃ–WÃ–LFÃ–F"` Does
 not match with input in browser.

So, somehow `ÄÖÄWFÖWÖLFÖF` is being converted into `Ã„Ã–Ã„WFÃ–WÃ–LFÃ–F` in IE10.

**Thoughts**

I'm just shooting blanks into the air here but, could this possbly be a decoding/encoding issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

You need to check the charset of your database, webpage (in <meta>-tag or http-header), charset of your .asp pages / vbscripts, the VB6 component etc. The **entire** pipeline, **front-to-back**, needs to "agree" (or, alternatively, provide an explicit "conversion") on the encoding used.

Assuming you want to use UTF-8:

For meta-tags:

```
<!-- HTML5 -->
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<!-- HTML4 -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

VBScript:

```
Response.CodePage = 65001
Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
Response.ContentType = "text/html"
```

Ensure your database's charset is UTF-8 and make sure your VB6 component handles UTF-8 correct as well.

Comment: Thanks, i'll have a closer look.

Comment: Is it possible to convert a string on the fly or does the entire context need to be in sync?

Comment: All ASP pages have this meta resoruce: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5" />`

Comment: How about you read the link I gave in the answer? That answers your first question ("*does the entire context need to be in sync*"). Also, my post provides the answer (I even made it **bold** before you asked...). Regarding the meta-tag: It has nothing to do with charsets. How about you google `X-UA-Compatible`? That's the least you could do before wasting peoples time.